# Setting arrays in Wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array, set

I am currently trying to set up a search in Wordpress, though am having issues because I am currently losing the search term in the query. I believe this is because I am running a new query instead of setting the WP query.

### Current problem

Currently I am running the following command (an example where I wish to search taxonomies `feature` and `location` and the search term.

```
if ($s_feature != "" && $s_location != "")
    {
        $s_feat_array = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'feature',
            'terms' => array($s_feature),
            'field' => 'slug',
            'relation' => 'AND',
            );
        $s_loc_array = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'location',
            'terms' => array($s_location),
            'field' => 'slug',
            );
        $housequery['tax_query'] = array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            $s_feat_array,
            $s_loc_array
        );
        query_posts($housequery);
    }
```

Unfortunately, this is not searching the submitted search term nor any other queries.

### My attempt

I therefore think that it should be 'set' to `$query` rather than running a new command. I have seen that the following code DOES work:

```
$query->set('post_type',array('houses'));
```

However, I have tried to modify the query as follows and instead I get a fatal error (Call to member function on a non-object):

```
$query->set(array('taxonomy','location','terms',
array($s_location),'field',array('slug')));
```

I think it's to do with the array not being structured correctly though am really quite puzzled, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may want to try at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

`$housequery['tax_query']` is an item in an array at index tax_query. You then make that an array. But when you call query_posts, you do not reference `$housequery['tax_query']`.

Try `query_posts($housequery['tax_query']);` or remove tax_query completely if you can.

```
$housequery = array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            $s_feat_array,
            $s_loc_array
        );
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have just tried this with no luck - it ignores all the parameters when modifying it by adding `['tax_query']` to the query_posts or removing it from $housequery. Any suggestions as to what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I see what you were trying to do above now with `tax_query`. I'm not 100% sure whether `query_posts` accepts it or not. Maybe try using WP_Query? There is an example of using multiple taxonomies on this page. http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query